# How to remove document after moving from inbox in lotus script?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

I am moving a document from inbox to a custom folder it moves successfully but it still appearing in inbox. I want to remove it from inbox. I tried doc.RemoveFromFolder("Inbox") after moving but it does't work for me . Here is my code :

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
Set dc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument

Call doc.PutInFolder("Reported Emails")
Call doc.RemoveFromFolder("Inbox")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is absolutely ok, but you need to give the "real" name of the folder. Just check in your designer: The name of the folder that is titled "Inbox" in your client is named "($Inbox)" in Designer. Your code needs to use that:

```
Call doc.RemoveFromFolder("($Inbox)")
```

Comment: yeah bro i solved it can you please tell me how to refresh my view ?

Comment: you're welcome. Just one remark as I saw this in a lot of your questions: If you like an answer then upvote it. If it is the one that solves your problem, then give it the check mark as "accepted" answer in addtition to the upvote: a lot of your questions have accepted answers without an upvote. But upvotes are the currency in this community. Thank you. It is very common to upvote the answer that you selected as accepted as well.